# El significado del verbo "catar" en el Cantar de mío Cid

Tags: significado, poesía, español-medieval

> *La oraçion fecha, la missa acabada la han,*
>   *salieron de la eglesia, ya quieren cavalgar.*
>   *El Cid a doña Ximena-ivala abraçar.*
>   *Doña Ximena al Cid la manol va besar,*
>   *Llorando de los ojos, que non sabe qué se far.*
>   *E él a las niñas tornolas a **catar***:
>   *"a Diós vos acomiendo-e al Padre spirital;*
>   *agora nos partimos, Dios sabe el ajuntar"*

(Según es citado en **Las mejores Poesías de la Lengua Española** por **Angelina Gatell**)

¿Cuál es el significado del verbo ***catar*** en este contexto? Un diccionario de español moderno sólo me da la traducción "to sample" - as in testing food. Me parece que en este caso, "catar" se puede traducir mejor como "to advise, to give advice". A no ser que a Don Rodrigo Díaz de Vivar le haya gustado practicar el canibalismo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El [mapa de diccionarios](https://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) de la RAE proporciona acceso a seis versiones antiguas del Diccionario de la Lengua Española, empezando por la del año 1780. Buscando *catar*, encontramos que, incluso en 2001, uno de los significados era *mirar*:

> 3. tr. p. us. **mirar** (‖ dirigir la vista). U. t. c. prnl.

Este parece ser el significado de *catar* en el pasaje que citas.

Comment: De hecho, se encuentra en el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/catar?m=form).

Answer (score 3):

En una edición de español moderno, ese pasaje dice:

> La oración, una vez hecha, la misa acabada está;
>   salieron todos del templo; prepáranse a cabalgar.
>   El Cid a doña Jimena un abrazo le fue a dar
>   y doña Jimena al Cid la mano le va a besar,
>   con lágrimas en los ojos, que sólo saben llorar.
>   Y él a las niñas, con pena, tornábalas a **mirar**:
>   «Al Señor os encomiendo, al Padre espiritual;
>   nos separamos, ¡quién sabe si nos podremos juntar!»

Por lo que me parece que wimi tiene razón y aquí "catar" significa "mirar".

Comment: Gracias también por tu respuesta. Pero esa traducción al español moderno no suena ni remotamente tan bonita como el original...